# ¿Es correcto decir "Tostada de aguacate"?

Tags: traducción, gramática, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, comida

En este contexto, el aguacate es untado.  En inglés, no dirías "Avocado on toast", sino "avocado toast".

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de decir esto?

Comment: Im not sure if “untar” is the correct word for “spread”.

Comment: 1. Mi propio inglés sí admite "avocado on toast", pero no sé si tiene que ver realmente con esta pregunta. 2. La "tostada", ¿es pan o tortilla?

Comment: "pan tostado con aguacate" or "pan tostado con palta"

Comment: Excellent nickname @8protons. Welcome to Spanish SE.

Comment: @DGaleano Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

No, no creo que decir "tostada de aguacate" suene correcto. Debería decirse "tostada con aguacate". Aunque muchas veces la composición de dos palabras en inglés *A B* se pueda traducir al español como "*B* de *A*", en este caso se trata de algo diferente, porque la tostada es de pan y el aguacate está untado encima.

Si haces una torta (o pastel) y la rellenas de frutillas (fresas), puedes decir que es una torta **de** frutillas (o un pastel **de** fresas), porque la torta **está hecha de eso**. Pero si las frutillas/fresas están por encima, como decoración o agregado, a eso vas a llamarlo "torta **con** frutillas" (o "pastel **con** fresas").

Comment: Gracias. Usted escribió que cree que "tostada de aguacate" no es correcta, pero luego escribió "torta de frutillas" es correcta. Y no proporcionó una respuesta para lo que cree que es la redacción correcta. ¿Te importaría elaborar?

Comment: Edité un poco mi respuesta. La diferencia para mí es de cuánto está integrado el ingrediente. El aguacate está encima de un pedazo de pan tostado, no es parte de la receta del pan tostado en sí.

Comment: En Chile tenemos la _tartaleta de frutas_, que, sin embargo, sólo está cubierta con frutas.

Answer (score 2):

Siento disentir de [pablo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76), que es de lo mejorcito que tenemos por aquí pero ...

En mi tierra natal de Andalucía, España, **sí es correcto** ese uso que apuntas.

Recurramos al D.R.A.E para intentar respaldar el uso efectivo e idiomático que hacemos aquí con el significado que aparece en dicho diccionario

[**de**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=de)

> 4. prep. Denota la materia de que **está hecho** algo

Como digo, en esta parte del mundo, empleamos indistintamente "con" y "de" en relación a una tostada. Podemos decir indistintamente "una tostada **de** mantequilla y mermelada" o "una tostada **con** mantequilla y mermelada".

Supongamos que ese plato de la carta es el número tres, perfectamente podemos decir que el plato 3 **está hecho** de pan, mantequilla y mermelada. De todas las tostadas (como plato numerado de una carta) escogemos aquella que lleva como ingredientes, **elementos que son parte del plato** (otro de los significados de la preposición "de": pertenencia) mantequilla y mermelada. O aguacate en tu caso.

Otro ejemplo más internacional es el taco. Aunque es un plato mejicano, aquí podemos perfectamente pedir un taco de pollo, un taco de ternera o un taco de guacamole. La envoltura del taco está hecha de maíz y no de pollo, ternera o aguacate; pero en estos casos se antepone el "de" porque estos tres son el ingrediente principal con que está elaborado el plato, lo que distingue un taco de otro. Pues lo mismo podemos aplicar en las tostadas para distinguir una de otra.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con las dos afirmaciones: 1 que Pablo es de los buenos  y 2 que si es correcto o por lo menos regional decir "de aguacate". En Colombia aplica tal como lo describes.

Comment: @DGaleano al leer esta pregunta, sin querer me vino a la mente un plátano *con* hogao... (acá mismo en Colombia) igual una empanada es con ají o con guacamole... (no sé si es por el hecho que el hogao, el ají y el guacamole son producidos, a diferencia del maíz, el pollo o el aguacate...)